# Perl to php similar functions for escape and encode

Tags: php, perl, unicode, escaping, encode

I have this part of perl code and I want to find a similar code in PHP. 
(I don't know perl, only php)

```
my $encoded_string = encode( 'UTF8', $not_latin_string );
my $escaped_string = Unicode::Escape::escape($encoded_string);
```

The result will then be bcrypt and store as password.

I tried different methods but are not working correctly. So if someone knows perl and php and can help me I will be thankful.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `utf8_encode()` ?

Comment: @Moppo I have tried with this code: $encoded_string = utf8_encode($not_latin_string);
$escaped_string = mb_convert_encoding($encoded_string, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');  But the final result is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Escape unicode character:

```
<?php

function unicode_escape($str) {
    $str_utf16_be = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-16BE");
    $chunks = str_split(bin2hex($str_utf16_be), 4);
    return implode("", preg_filter("/^/", "\\u", $chunks));
}

$not_latin_string = '野屋の牛丼食べたい';
echo unicode_escape($not_latin_string);
```

output:

```
\ud842\udfb7\u91ce\u5c4b\u306e\u725b\u4e3c\u98df\u3079\u305f\u3044
```

Do you really need this function?  Have you tried `json_encode`?